# true is not being printed out on first run. instead false is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why does this return false, in the first run; when it's meant to return true.

I have a state with a name   `const [dataFromServer] = useState({name:["john"]})`
this codes checks to see if the above name is in my file, if it does it should update the state to true.

```
const [uploadStatus,UploadStateSetState] = useState("false")

    const  onSubmittt =   (e) => {
         e.preventDefault() 
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedFile.length; i++) {
          if (dataFromServer.name.includes(selectedFile[i].people)) 
          { 
            UploadStateSetState("true")
            break; 
        }
       }
    
       
        <button onClick={onSubmittt}>submit</button>
```

Comment: @PatrickEvans that line was for testing purposes.i've edited the ask

Comment: And, `selectedFile` doesn't exist. You posted this same question a couple of hours ago but apparently didn't read any of the comments. You need to provide a [mcve] for us to help debug your code.

Comment: @Andy i belive thats enough info for the help. i just wanted the UploadStateSetState("true") to change the state of uploadStatus if conditions in the for is met. It only works on a second run. but i want it to run on the first run if condition is met

First Run  : False
Second Run : True
Third Run : True

Comment: Clearly it's not enough information because you've had to ask the same question twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react js console.log returning false instead of true in first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68881892/react-js-console-log-returning-false-instead-of-true-in-first-run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the react Hooks rule guideline.

**Don’t call Hooks inside loops,**

[Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)